# Multiple background urls, repeat, and size

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind 3, and I'm trying to get this effect:

```
background: url('img1.png') repeat 20%, url('img2.png') no-repeat;
```

I tried all kinds of things like this was getting close:

`bg-[url("img1.png"),url("img2.png")] bg-[length:20%,auto] bg-repeat`

but I'm not able to make the bg-repeat arbitraty to make it repeat the first one and not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, something like `bg-[repeat-x,repeat-y]` doesn't work and there is nothing about it in the docs.
Seems like you'll have to use pseudos ::before and ::after...

Answer (score 1):

Here's some discussion about making different `bg` properties work: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7444

To summarize, custom `bg-repeat` doesn't seem possible.